# htaccess redirect from website.com/?u=1&name=john to website.com/1/john

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Found this, but i want to have to query strings done.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile\.php\?u=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new redirect and rewrite rule for 2 parameters:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile\.php\?u=([^\s&]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile\.php\?u=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ok this does redirect to website.com/1/john, but the controller fails to recognize it, can we still have profile.php?u=$1&name=$2 on the server to be understood by PHP?

Comment: This new rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]` is actually making it `profile.php?u=$1&name=$2` internally.